# How to create HTTP PUT Request on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, httpwebrequest, httprequest, httpconnection, http-put

To give some background:
I'm building a BlackBerry frontend to talk to a backend web service built to support only PUT requests for a lot of important resources instead of POST requests.

This backend worked fine for iOS but I can't seem to create a PUT request on the BlackBerry. Looking through the BlackBerry API, I've been able to create GET/POST requests with the following code:

```
HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(URL);  
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
```

or

```
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
```

It seems that the HttpConnection class should support a PUT command as seen in the API [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29). I've tried manually setting `conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");` but I keep getting a 400 error from the server.

Does anyone know how to properly create a PUT request for the BlackBerry? My search throughout the web hasn't brought back any usable solutions so far. =( Thanks!

Comment: Simply adding the 'conn.setRequstMethod( "PUT" )' worked in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 400 means "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.".

So could you confirm your code works OK if you use `conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);`?

Here is why I'm asking this:
According to RESTful web services pattern the difference should be in that PUT is used to update a resource on server while POST is used to create a resource on server. So if your networking code works OK as a POST, then it confirms your code is basically OK.

Another point is "what framework/technology is used on server side?". This could be important, because browsers do not support PUTs (only GET and POST) natively, so web-apps usually simulate PUTs by putting a hidden form field (smth like "_method=PUT") in web-forms. So when user clicks Submit, then browser does a POST which includes "_method=PUT" param, so the server can recognize it is a PUT. This is used in Rails and I suspect others do some similar stuff. If this is your case, then just try appending your POST params with a required by your web-app param (smth like "_method=PUT").

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tested POST on a very simple resource earlier, and it worked fine. But to my surprise, it ended up with a 400 after you made me try again. A bit more testing and I figured out my problem - my content-type header was incorrect. After fixing it, both POST & PUT commands are working now, so THANK YOU!

Comment: I'm glad it turned to be so simple. :)